# How init is identified when creating an instance?

Tags: swift

As per swift Docs

> Conversely, if you write a subclass initializer that matches a superclass convenience initializer, that superclass convenience initializer can never be called directly by your subclass, as per the rules described above in Initializer Delegation for Class Types.

from the above paragraph, we can able to see that our compiler is identifying  our init(Convenience and Designated), How it's possible because the init method doesn't have any name, My doubt is how it's comparing our subclass and superclass init

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Could you please provide a code sample illustrating your question?

Comment: if you read the paragraph     you can able to see that complier is comapring init? but how they are comparing?@Sulthan

Comment: The compiler knows what initializer is convenience because 1. there must be `convenience` keyword 2. convenience init contains some `self.init(...)` call

Comment: I can understand your explanation but can you kindly elaborate the sentence from the above yellow bar?@Sulthan